# Что нужно знать для разработки веб приложений с помощью платформы .Net?

Tags: .net

Я хочу заниматься разработкой веб-приложений, веб-сайтов с помощью платформы .Net. Фактически хочу выучиться на веб-программиста. Платформа .net предоставляет множество инструментов для разработки данных вещей(asp.net, silverlight и т.д.). Но я не имею знаний и опыта в основах программирования, поэтому у меня сложился вопрос, нужно ли мне изучать следующие вещи и делать следующие моменты?

1. Язык С#. Изучаю сейчас по книге Шилдта, пишу учебный проект(телефонный справочник), выполняю упражнения по каждой теме из книги Шилдта.
2. Изучить основы ООП, например по книге Гради Буча Объектно-ориентированный анализ и проектирование с примерами приложений
3. Изучить алгоритмы и структуры данных
4. Прочесть книгу по ОС
5. Прочесть книгу по компьютерным сетям

Также прошу дать советы, как правильно мне идти по данному пути

Comment: "Но я не имею знаний и опыта в основах программирования" ну так с этого и начните, а там, "глядишь", и вопросы отпадут

Answer (score 1):

1, 2 - обязательно. 3 - основы знать необходимо, но в дебри влезать лучше по мере надобности, специально забивать себе голову не стоит. 4, 5 - в принципе, не обязательно, больше для общего развития. Про сети достаточно понимать два аспекта трафика: количество обращений по сети, количество данных, передаваемых при обращениях.

Кроме того, обязательно надо знать языки, на которых пишется код, выполняемый в браузере: HTML, JavaScript и css, методологию Web-дизайна (что касается семантической вёрстки).

Ну и большинство сайтов работают на базе данных, так что необходимы знания в этом направлении. Во-первых, теория (реляционная алгебра), во-вторых, практика - умение работать с конкретной (-ыми) СУБД, знание её диалекта SQL.

Answer (score 0):

для работы с веб на платформе .нет есть две похожих технологии asp.net и asp.net mvc. Первая более популярная, вторая более новая и более перспективная. Сам лично пишу на mvc для начала могу посоветовать видео уроки на [teachdays.ru](http://teachdays.ru). Также еще нужно знать принципы работы с базами данных (желательно именно MS SQL Server) и базовые знания верстки и т.п. Собственно вот и все))